# How to Access To A Zip File on Server Using JQuery Ajax - No Need to Download

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can you please let me know how I can get a ZIP file stored on same server using the jquery Ajax? Please be informed that I do not want to download the file
I need to pass the result , if success? to an API snippet like this, (this is using a Form to pass a zip file from client to the `request` Here is [The Working Demo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=portal_addshapefile)

```
request({
    url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
    content: myContent,
    form: dom.byId('uploadForm'),
    handleAs: 'json',
    load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
    if (response.error) {
      errorHandler(response.error);
      return;
    }
    var layerName = response.featureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;
      addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
    }),
    error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
});
```

but I need to pass the zip file from server witout using a form and here is what I would like to do

```
var data = "www.mydomain.com/GIS/App.ZIP";
 request({
 ....,
 form: data,
 ....
});
```

> Update

As menitoned API offers the Formdata option as well but how I can pass second parameter of type inside the append method?

```
var theFile  = "http://localhost/Portal/APP.ZIP";
 var myFormData = new FormData();
 myFormData.append(theFile, ? );
```

Comment: You can download a zip file into ram and then send it to another server. If you need to unzip it you can use [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)

Comment: Thanks for comment , but how? besides, I do not want to unzip it , I just want to pass to the form option of the request

Comment: It says in the [API docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html#esrirequest-request-form) that you can use a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Comment: you are right but couldn't fins a way to append the `App.ZIP` to the instance of Formdata! Please take a look at update

Comment: Did you try `myFormData.append("file", blob);`? There is some information on how to create a blob [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot access the local filesystem without user intervention for security reasons. A user must take an action to load a file. Otherwise, it would be very easy for malicious web pages to traverse your file system.

You can use javascript via AJAX to trigger a server side script which can access the server file system and return results to javascript though.

Comment: Thansk for comment but as I said in the post what I need is not loading from client machine! I need to pass the zip file which is sitting on the server. like referencing to a URL in ajax call var data = "www.domain.com/GIS/App.ZIP"